# Free memory while programming functionally in C

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to find out the best way to program functionally in C, but I'm having a problem in freeing the memory after being allocated.

consider the following example: (I deleted the unimportant parts because I thought it would be too long)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char* someFunction(int someParam)
{
    //... some code ...
    char* str = malloc((strlen)*sizeof(char));
    //... some code ...
    return(str);
}

int main()
{
    //... some code ...
    printf("%s\n", someFunction(someParam))
    return 0;
}
```

Here, since someFunction is called inside printf, and there seems to be no way to free the memory that's been allocated for the string. Note that this code DOES compile with GCC, but I'm looking for a way to reduce the memory load overall.

I could define a temporary variable and free it later in the main function, but the code would be more difficult to read as the functions get nested more.

Comment: That's a memory leak; assign it a variable in `main` and then `free` would be a way to fix it.

Comment: "but the code would be more difficult to read". Making the code easier to read is definetely important but is secondary to making the code functionally correct. So your idea of a temp variable is the right way to do it.

Comment: I was hoping to do scheme or lisp-style heavily nested functions, but i guess that would be difficult.

Comment: An alternative style is for the caller to provide the memory and pass that as a pointer into the function. In that case the caller can use an auto variable that doesn't need to be freed or in the case of `main` it can even use dynamic memory which will be freed automatically when the process exits. Of course there are tradeoffs with that approach as well such as avoiding large auto variables on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a temporary variable so you can free it later. Otherwise you'll have a memory leak each time you call the function like this.

C doesn't have any form of automatic memory management, except that most operating systems will reclaim all of the process's private memory when it terminates. Unfortunately, this means that your program will need to be a little more verbose.

Comment: I think the operating system is the one responsible for freeing memory at termination, but this is probably being very pedantic. +1

Comment: @Neil Right. I assumed that freeing all memory was one of the cleanups that `exit()` does, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have that functional style, you can pass an additional (pointer) argument where you record whatever needs to be cleaned up:

```
char* someFunction(int someParam, void **cleanup)
{
    //... some code ...
    char* str = malloc((strlen)*sizeof(char));
    //... some code ...
    *cleanup = str;
    return(str);
}

int main()
{
    void *cleanup = 0;
    //... some code ...
    printf("%s\n", someFunction(someParam, &cleanup));
    free(cleanup);
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to extend this, you can replace the simple `void *` with a data structure that can record multiple pointers that need later cleanup, and add multiple allocated things to it, and then clean them up all at once at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Simply allocate the buffer in main and pass it as a parameter to the function so that it may populate it. 
This way you don't have to have global variables.

```
//... some code ...

int someFunction(int someParam, char *output, int somesize)
{
    //... some code ...
    // update a maximum of 'somesize' of  output
    snprintf(output, somesize, "some special string");
    //... some code ...        
    return strlen("some special string");
}

int main()
{
    char buffer[somesize]; // or use malloc and free at the end
    //... some code ...
    if (someFunction(someParam, buffer, somesize) > 0) {
       printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was why I did not add them :)

Comment: `status` is unused, which could cause .problems it it's describing the validity of `buffer`.

Comment: does it really need to be a full example ? :)

Comment: I get the point, but unfortunately, the size of the string is unknown beforehand. So I would probably stick to malloc() inside someFunction and freeing the returned value in main()

Comment: Clearly depends on what you are doing but, you could return an error if the buffer is not big enough, or have a custom type that is passed as parameter. Ie. instead of "char *output, int somesize" have "MyType *var;" where MyType could be "typedef struct { int size; char *buffer;};" so that you allocate it in main and call it as: "MyType 
 var; someFunction(someParam, &var);" and in someFunction you allocate the buffer. then create a helper to free(MyType );